# Using AJAX to load form input and new error div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form that asks the basic questions, here's the html:

```
  <form method="post" action="<url goes here>" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="register">

  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="tableQuestion">Your Name (character name/gaming handle):&nbsp;*</td>
      <td class="tableAnswer"><input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" autocomplete="off"/></td><td class="tableStatus"><div id="username-status"></div></td>
    </tr>

  <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
  <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif">
  </span>
  <span id="result_1">
  </span>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="FormSubmit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

And then there is the ajax-check.php which inserts a question in the span. It creates more than the one question but for the purpose of this I put only one. The div created in the ajax request is always named '#inputid'+'-status'

```
if(isset($_GET['game']) && $_GET['drop_var']=="2"){
    echo "<hr/>";
    echo "<center><h2>Planet Side 2</h2></center>";
    echo "<table border=\"0\">  ";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class=\"tableQuestion\">Your Name (character name/gaming handle):&nbsp;*</td>";
    echo "<td class=\"tableAnswer\"><input id=\"ps2-main\" type=\"text\" name=\"ps2-main\" /></td><td class=\"tableStatus\"><div id=\"ps2-main-status\"></div></td>";
    echo "</tr> ";
    echo "</table>  ";
}
```

Using a validate plugin works on all the questions(input) except the new ones. sample below: It would print the error message in the div #username-status. So in the example below username works. However it does not work for ps2-main. I know it has something to do with the DOM.

I've looked up how to do it but I either don't understand or I'm doing it wrong and thus why I'm here for some help. I've read using live() but I'm not sure how to implement it in this. I've got it submitting the data right. But I want to be able to validate it. Any thoughts? Is there a better way?

```
$(function(){
  jQuery("#username").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL.length > 5 && VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter a name"
  });

  jQuery("#ps2-main").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL.length > 5 && VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter a name"
  });
});
```

Comment: I have no idea why you put "; on end of these <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">"; <img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif">";
  </span>"; 
  <span id="result_1">";
  </span>;    Any idea for this?

Comment: My bad, its cause I had this in a php and I was using echo. forgot to remove those. Fixed.

Comment: One more, second block code is also wrong. You write down directly html inside php without using echo or php open and close tag.

Comment: Which validation plugin are you using?

Comment: @ K-Thiha I cleaned it up so it would be easier to read. Not actually functional. Put it back with the echos.

Comment: @ Sparky Validation is by http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/ It served my purposes the best.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution. But I found something that works. I thought I would post my solution here so if someone else came upon it they could at least have a solution.

I simply added the jquery script into the ajax. At the end of

```
echo "</table>";
```

I put

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ps2_main").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.length > 5 && VAL) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please enter a name"
    });
});
</script>
```

This worked for me.